# Compressing Images in Compressed PDF with SetaPDF API in PHP - How?

Tags: php, pdf, compression, setapdf

I've been working on a PHP script to compress PDF files using GhostScript, and I've successfully achieved that. However, I now want to further compress the images within the already compressed PDF. I heard that I can use the SetaPDF API for this purpose. Can anyone confirm if this is true, and if so, could you please guide me on how to accomplish this? I've searched online but couldn't find any relevant information.

I would greatly appreciate any help or pointers you can provide regarding possible solutions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's currently no compression feature for images nor its structure integrated in SetaPDF.